# How to save https response to variable and use for another function?

Tags: node.js, api, response

I would like to save nodejs https response for global variable and use it later. I know it is assync function but I'm not fully understand therefore I can not implement it. I would thanksfull if somebody can help me out and show me how to make it work.

The code:

```
function getPageContent() {             
  
    const postData = `some data`;

    const options = {                                            
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'sitepage',
        path: "/path",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + 'apikey'
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('getPageContent statusCode:', res.statusCode);

        res.on('data', (d) => {                                       
            answer += d;  
            return answer   => This is what I would like to save.
        });

    });

    req.write(postData);                                          
    req.end();
}; 

getPageContent()
console.log(answer)
```

As an answer of console log I would like to see the https answer but with my code it is blank.

Comment: How would you like to use it later?

Comment: You will find your programming life a lot easier if you use a higher level http request library such as `got()`, `axios()`, `node-fetch()` or `fetch()` which is built-in to the latest versions of nodejs.  Those are all promise-based and will read the whole response for you, resulting in cleaner, simpler code.

Comment: @Konrad, what do you mean? I would like to use data what I receive. eg.: input for the next function().

Comment: If this data is per user you can use session. If it's global, you can just use a global variable